# How to write quotient algebra for normalizer?

Tags: lie-algebras

For Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\{e1,e2,e3,e4\}$ with commutations $[e1, e3]=\,e1, [e2, e3]=\,\alpha\,e2$, I have calculated normalizer for sub-algebra $\mathfrak{q}=\,\{e1+e2\}$ as

$\text{Nor}_{\mathfrak{g}}\left(\mathfrak{q}\right)=\,\{e1, e2, e4\}$.

I wonder what could be the quotient algebra $\frac{\text{Nor}_{\mathfrak{g}}\left(\mathfrak{q}\right)}{\mathfrak{q}}$ ?

I can explain how I use to calculate quotient algebra, for example, for sub-algebra $\mathfrak{p}=\{e1\}$, the normalizer is $\text{Nor}_{\mathfrak{g}}\left(\mathfrak{p}\right)=\,\{e1, e2, e3, e4\}$ and for quotient algebra $\frac{\text{Nor}_{\mathfrak{g}}\left(\mathfrak{p}\right)}{\mathfrak{p}}$, I simply remove $e1$ from $\text{Nor}_{\mathfrak{g}}\left(\mathfrak{p}\right)$ and obtain quotient algebra for normalizer as

$\frac{\text{Nor}_{\mathfrak{g}}\left(\mathfrak{p}\right)}{\mathfrak{p}}=\,\{e2, e3, e4\}$

But in above case I don't know how to proceed. This problem seems to be too simple for experts in Lie algebra, but as I  belong to applied mathematics so I feel handicapped here, Please help !!

PS. I have calculated these normalizers using Lie Algebra package in Maple.

Comment: Are $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ basis elements of $\mathfrak{g}$? If so, then how is the Lie algebra structure determined by the two given relations; for example, what about $[e_1, e_2]$? (Are all pairs of basis elements other than the ones given assumed to commute?)

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Yes they form basis and e4 is central element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumming that $[e_1, e_2] = [e_1, e_4] = [e_2, e_4] = [e_3, e_4] = 0$ we have
$$
  \operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})
  =
  \begin{cases}
    \langle e_1, e_2, e_4 \rangle
     & \text{if $\alpha \neq 1$}, \\
    \langle e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4 \rangle
    & \text{if $\alpha = 1$},
  \end{cases}
$$
where $\langle - \rangle$ denotes the linear span. (The computation can be found below.)

We first consider the case $\alpha \neq 1$.
Then
$$
     \operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})
  =  \langle e_1, e_2, e_4 \rangle
  =  \langle e_1 + e_2, e_2, e_4 \rangle
$$
with the three generators being a basis.
Therefore
$$
    \operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q}) / \mathfrak{q}
  = \langle \overline{e_2}, \overline{e_4} \rangle,
$$
where $\overline{x}$ denotes the residue class of $x \in \operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})$, and the two generators being a basis.
Because $e_4$ is central in $\mathfrak{g}$ we find that $\overline{e_4}$ is central in $\operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q}) / \mathfrak{q}$.
So $\operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q}) / \mathfrak{q}$ is the two-dimensional abelian Lie algebra.

Consider now the case $\alpha = 1$, i.e. $[e_2, e_3] = e_2$.
Then
$$
    \operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})
  = \langle e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4 \rangle
  = \langle e_1 + e_2, e_2, e_3, e_4 \rangle
$$
with the four generators being a basis.
Therefore
$$
    \operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q}) / \mathfrak{q}
  = \langle \overline{e_2}, \overline{e_3}, \overline{e_4} \rangle
$$
with the three generators being a basis.
As before we find that $\overline{e_4}$ is central, but in this case we also have the addition relation
$$
  [\overline{e_2}, \overline{e_3}] = \overline{e_2}.
$$
So $\operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q}) / \mathfrak{q}$ is the direct sum of the two-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra $\langle \overline{e_2}, \overline{e_3} \rangle$ and the one-dimensional (abelian) Lie algebra $\langle \overline{e_4} \rangle$.

---

**Edit:** I computed the normalizer $\operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})$ as follows: We have
$$
  [e_1, e_1 + e_2] = [e_2, e_1 + e_2] = [e_4, e_1 + e_2] = 0
$$
and
$$
      [e_3, e_1 + e_2]
  = - [e_1 + e_2, e_3]
  = - [e_1, e_3] - [e_2, e_3]
  = - e_1 - \alpha e_2.
$$
So we have $e_1, e_2, e_4 \in \operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})$, independent of $\alpha$.

If $\alpha = 1$ then
$$
      [e_3, e_1 + e_2]
  = - e_1 - \alpha e_2
  = - e_1 - e_2
  = -(e_1 + e_2)
  \in \langle e_1 + e_2 \rangle
  = \mathfrak{q},
$$
so in this case we also have $e_3 \in \operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})$ and thus $\operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q}) = \langle e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4 \rangle = \mathfrak{g}$.

If $\alpha \neq 1$ then $-e_1 - \alpha e_2$ is no scalar multiple of $e_1 + e_2$, and thus $e_3 \notin \operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})$.
In particular $\operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q}) \neq \mathfrak{q}$, which is why $\operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})$ is at most three-dimensional.
Because $\operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})$ already contains the three linear independent elements $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_4$ we also know that $\operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})$ is at least three dimensional.
Hence $\operatorname{Nor}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{q})$ must be three-dimensional and thus equals its three-dimensional subspace $\langle e_1, e_2, e_4 \rangle$.

Comment: How did you write $\langle e_1, e_2, e_4 \rangle
  =  \langle e_1 + e_2, e_2, e_4 \rangle$ ?

Comment: In Maple when I use SubalgebraNormalizer command for $\{e1+e2\} $, it returns Normalizer as $ \{e1, e2, e4\} $, but you are computing it very different, why is it so ?

Comment: I added my calculation of the normalizer. For your first question you need to check for each of the two subspaces that its generators are contained in the other one. For $e_2$ and $e_4$ this is clear, and for the other two we have $e_1 = (e_1 + e_2) - e_2$. (This is very basic linear algebra.)

Comment: Thank you for sparing time on such basic calculations.

Comment: With similar argument in vector space, can I write like $e_{2}=\,(e_{1}+e_{2})-e_{2}$, so that $\langle e_1, e_2, e_4 \rangle
  =  \langle e_1 , e_1 + e_2, e_4 \rangle$ and in this way $\text{Nor}_{\mathfrak{g}}(\mathfrak{q})/\mathfrak{q}=\,\langle e_1,  e_4 \rangle$, am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, this also works.